# Cant configure Resource Qualifier (xamarin)

Tags: visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

Created an empty Android application (via xamarin). The Resource Qualifier (UI Mode) has several display modes.there are a Normal, Car Dock, a Desk Dock, a Television, an Appliance, a Watch. To remove the panel selected, in the photo you need to select Watch. But I make the application for the usual Andorid device. Is it possible to remove this panel in Normal mode? Or how to customize it?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVlGd.png)

Thanks.

Comment: You want delete the "ExampleApp" in the your picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to remove this panel in Normal mode?

This is an [ActionBar](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.ActionBar/) in `Android`, if you want delete it, just need use  `ActionBar.Hide()` like this :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    this.ActionBar.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but not perfect.there is a delay during sturtup and before the panel fades. Approximately 1.5 seconds. How remove it due to in axml it do not?

Comment: I just change the theme to the MaterialNoAstionBar in the designer. Is this a good way to solve the problem?

Comment: Understood by this article -https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/tool-bar/part-1-replacing-the-action-bar/